# Why isn't "Permission denied" in stderr?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, stderr

I have a command: `mywritercmd -f /tmp/test 2>&1 > log.txt` I run in a bash terminal, the command returns `error: could not open output file "/tmp/test": Permission denied`

Nevertheless, this error message isn't written in the **log.txt** file, it stays empty...

#### Why?

I'd have guessed this message should go to stderr and then in the file but somehow it isn't.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/117549 specifically the "left to right" part. You've redirected stderr to where stdout is/was, *then* redirected stdout to the log file.

Comment: Yes it does. I didn't search enough to find this answered question. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordering causes the difference. The command line is evaluated from left to right. When it reaches `2>&1`, the instruction is to deliver stderr to wherever stdout goes. At this point, the `> log.txt` part has not been evaluated yet. As a result, the stderr remains at the default, which is to output to the terminal.

`mywritercmd -f /tmp/test > log.txt 2>&1` will result in the behaviour that you want, and cause the error message to be written to the log.txt file.

Comment: This is the first time I've gotten a real explanation for this quirk.  Intuitively it should be the reverse because we claim stderr is being redirected to stdout, but really it's to the destination of stdout.

Comment: You can treat the "&" as meant the _current_ location.  So "2>&1 > /tmp/log.txt " means "send stderr to the current place stdout goes and _then_ send stdout to log.txt"

Comment: Think of `&` as its meaning in C: the "address of"

Comment: I mistakenly and unconsciously thought it would be processed from left to right (more or less like a pipe).  `1. Run the command`, `2. Redirect stderr to stdout`, `3. stdout (with stderr) into a file`. But I was wrong in the way all that works. Thanks!